# Data Types in oracle-Not sure to decide on which to use

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

For Sybase,I use the following datatypes.
Can anyone suggest me the oracle equivalent for the same
int8,int16,int32, char name[233],char name1,char name[256],ScaledDecimal64_t

Please let me know the oracle equivalent for the above datatype which has been defined in the C(generated code for sybase)

Answer (score 1):

Would the Sybase to Oracle datatype mappiong grid on this page help?

http://www.indiana.edu/~dss/Services/DataWarehouse/Oracle/Sybase/conversion.html